# Implementing a Triplet class in C++ STL

Tags: comparator

In one of the programming competition (past), I had a requirement to store set of unordered triplets in a map to count the frequencies of each of them. How can I implement a C++ class for the same.

I have written the following code.

```
struct Triplet
{
    long long v[3]; 

    Triplet(long long x,long long y, long long z)
    {
        v[0] = x;
        v[1] = y;
        v[2] = z;
        sort( v, v+3 );
    }
};
class  TripletCompare
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Triplet &t1, const Triplet &t2)
    {
        if( t1.v[0] < t2.v[0] )
            return true;
        else if( t1.v[0] == t2.v[0] && t1.v[1] < t2.v[1] )
            return true;
        else if( t1.v[0] == t2.v[0] && t1.v[1] == t2.v[1] && t1.v[2] < t2.v[3] )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

And in the main function, I have used them as follows.

```
map<Triplet,int,TripletCompare> m;
```

I was trying to insert different triplets into this map like (1,2,3) (2,1,3), (3,1,2) These are added as a single entry in my Visual Studio 2010 compiler. But is giving a different result in other compilers (http://ideone.com/sX1UQG)

However I could easily write a Java class which works fine.

```
class Triplet
{
    public long []v;
    public Triplet(long a, long b, long c)
    {
        v = new long[3];
        v[0] = a;
        v[1] = b;
        v[2] = c;
        Arrays.sort(v);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return (int)(v[0] * 11 + v[1] *23 + v[2]*41);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        Triplet t = (Triplet)o;
        if( v[0] == t.v[0] && v[1] == t.v[1] && v[2] == t.v[2])
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I do this in C++?

Comment: This is a typo: `t1.v[2] < t2.v[3]` should be `t1.v[2] < t2.v[2]`. In any case, you should use [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) rather than rolling your own.

Comment: If you use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) rather than a built-in array, you even get the comparison for free. It really pays to use standard/library components.

Comment: @Mankarse, thanks for your inputs. Let me check with std::array as even using lexicographic_compare I am not able to solve my problem.

Comment: but std::arrays is in C++ 11. Is there any other way without moving to C++ 11?

Comment: There is [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/array.html).

Comment: I think your problem is that your functionality check is incorrect. I would expect your code to print `0`, since every time that there is a duplicate, you call `m[t]++;`, and so the mapped value is not ever equal to `1` (but is rather equal to `3`), so unique never gets incremented.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/wx3La6

Comment: What does Visual Studio do? The GCC output is what would be expected.